# Location change and controller managing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. I am not sure my question is right because I don't know the technical language. My problem is with the last URL path segment between two pages (One is listing page , second is detail page).

This is listing page url  `.........#/modelList/`

When I click on link the url changes to `.........#/modelList/2` (added correspond row number in url - see below html code ) - **my problem here see last paragraph**

Then I can get detail page data from this value (see this line in controller `$routeParams` and `$scope.carBrand = response.data[$scope.id]` )

Example Array

```
data[
    { brand: 'nokia', model: 'modelOne'}
    { brand: 'nokia', model: 'modelTwo'}
    { brand: 'nokia', model: 'modelThree'}
]
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in phoneBrandList.data">
    <td><a href="#/modelList/{{$index}}">{{list.brand}} </a></td>
</tr>
```

controller for detail page

```
controller('carModelController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id
    alert($scope.id)
    $http.get("apidata.js")
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.carBrand = response.data[$scope.id]
      })
})
```

Everything fine yet -

now I want to add last word in url  `/nokia` instead of number `/2` but i don't lost **corresponding** detail page data from  `$scope.carBrand = response.data[$scope.id]`

Ask me if my question is not clear 
Thanks for your help -

Comment: you need to change url from `#/modelList/` to `#/modelList` so that it will not confuse the `$routeProvider`

Comment: `$index` is not a good idea for creating permanent url's...that index can easily change causing bookmark and SEO problems.

Comment: I know that that is why asked here how to change url

Comment: Please any example code @pankajparkar

Comment: yeah,so if your url is say "#/modelList/{{$index}}" , do u want to modify it to "#/modelList/{{$index}}/nokia"? can you explain what exactly you want..

Comment: I think this is better:    #/modelList/nokia

Answer (score 0):

okay,so you can try something like this..
In your template

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in phoneBrandList.data" ng-init=getUrl($index)>
    <td><a href=url() ng-click="changeUrl()>{{list.brand}} </a></td>
</tr>
```

and in your controller

```
controller('carModelController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.url=undefined;
    $scope.getUrl=function(index){
       $scope.url="#/modelList/$index";
    }
     $scope.changeUrl = function(){
        $scope.url="#/modelList/nokia";
     }
    alert($scope.id)
    $http.get("apidata.js")
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.carBrand = response.data[$scope.id]
      })
})
```

if ng-click doesnt't works,because it gives more priority to  href,if that is the case then use buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure - I think this is better idea

```
   <tr ng-repeat="list in phoneBrandList.data">
        <td><a href="#/modelList/{{$index}}/phonebrand">{{list.brand}} </a></td>
    </tr>
```

change route provider path based on link